# Get salesforce survey responses for partner community user enabled contact related list

Tags: community, experience-cloud, survey, salesforce-survey

I have Added survey on Experience cloud site and in salesforce created some contacts having Partner account and Enabled that contact as a Partner community user. Whenever the login to Community site and fill the survey then survey invitation and response should be come in related list of that contact.

1.If I manually created invitation by clicking generate survey invitation on contact record and fill the survey using that link then we can see survey responses in related list with that contact record because participant is populating on manually generated survey invitation record.

2.To implement above functionally I have created salesforce flow to get survey invitation to that user.
Flow is record triggered flow having object user and criteria:isportalenabled=true
also created resource participant={!record.id} where record is user record.

4.But still participant is not populating with that invitation link on survey invitation record.

5.if I try to send unique link then error occurs that salesforce can't generate unique link for experience cloud site user.

Please help me on this If required let me know for reference images. Thanks in advance.